# I want to fetch all the user with there created places using the vitrual populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, virtual

```
const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
    
try {

       await User.find({}).populate('place').exec(function(error, data) {
            console.log(data.places)
         console.log(data)
         res.json("ok")
          });        
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }

}
```

the virtual define for user is this.

```
userSchema.virtual('places',{

    ref: "Place",
    localField: "id",
    foreignField: "creator",
    
})
```

when i use findById for one user it work but when i use find it's not working

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the name of the virtual are not the same. place != places

as far as i can see in the docs here: the names should be the same
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
await User.find({}).populate('place').exec(function(error, data) {
```

need to be changed to :

```
await User.find({}).populate('places').exec(function(error, data) {
```

Comment: i have try but not working. This is working for one document but when we fetch all it no working